# How to write unit test for my function which I use to query dyanmoDB Table?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb

I use dynogels to scan the orphan data/zombie data on my dynamoDB Table, below is example.

```js
var Foo= 
dynogels.define('Account', {
  hashKey : 'email',

  // add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps : true,

  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    account   : Joi.string(), ---> this account is the id in Account table
    age     : Joi.number(),
    roles   : dynogels.types.stringSet(),
    settings : {
      nickname      : Joi.string(),
      acceptedTerms : Joi.boolean().default(false)
    }
  }
});
var Account = dynogels.define('Account', {
  hashKey : 'email',

  // add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps : true,

  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    name    : Joi.string(),
    id     : Joi.number(),
    roles   : dynogels.types.stringSet(),
    settings : {
      nickname      : Joi.string(),
      acceptedTerms : Joi.boolean().default(false)
    }
  }
});
function scanAccount(){
  
  if(!attributeName && !FooList[attribute.id]){
     return Account.scan().execAsync();
     } 
  }
```

The logic is, if the Foo Table doesn't have this account, the account is orphan data. 
Should I write unit test for this function? 
Or I should just write a function to query those id in Account table to test if they are exist?
If I write unit test, then I will still need to query the dynamoDB to check if the value is correct, since I have more than 1000+ to check if those account id doesn't exist in Foo Table, but I'm not sure if this is still the way to do the unit test?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, writing unit tests for the `scanAccount` method would look something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
function when_attributeName_and_notFooHasAttribute_and_accountHasData_returnData() {
  // setup mock Account
  // setup scan().execAsync() on mockAccount to return some test data
  // set attributeName = 'TEST-NAME'
  // setup mock empty FooList

  // invoke scanAccount()

  // assert that you received data as expected
}

function when_notAttributeName_returnUndefined() {
  // setup mock Account
  // setup scan().execAsync() on mockAccount to return some test data
  // set attributeName = undefined
  // setup mock empty FooList

  // invoke scanAccount()

  // assert that the result is undefined
}

function when_attributeName_and_FooHasAttribute_returnUndefined() {
  // setup mock Account
  // setup scan().execAsync() on mockAccount to return some test data
  // set attributeName = 'TEST'
  // setup FooList to contain attribute.id

  // invoke scanAccount()

  // assert that the result is undefined
}
```

There is value in writing such tests but don't mistake unit tests for integration tests. In writing unit tests you wouldn't be testing the retrieval of data, just that the logic of your `scanAccount` implementation is correct.

By the way, I'm not sure exactly what the intention of that method was, but it looks like it has some errors.. One way or another, just thinking about what tests you should write can help you find bugs. Writing the tests will make that definitive, and it will certainly help you with regression in the future!